# Typescript truthiness narrowing with conditional operators

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Considering the type [truthiness narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing) if we have the following types and variables.

```
type T = string | null | undefined; 
type T2 = string;

const getResult = (): T => '' as T;

const v1:T = getResult();
const v2:T = getResult();
```

The following script must not throw any error. As:

1. The `if` exhausts the truthiness for both variables.
2. After the `if` any of the `v1` and `v2` must exists.

```
if(!v1 && !v2) {
    throw new Error('Value Error');
}

const r: T2 = v1 ?? v2;
```

But the above script don't compile with following error on the assignment.

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

In contrast the following script works fine, thought the type narrowing must be same in both cases.

```
if(v1 && v2) {
    const r: T2 = v1 ?? v2;
}
```

Is it a some Typescript bug or some other issue?

Comment: The opposite of `v1 && v2` is not `!v1 && !v2` Using De Morgan's laws `not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B)` therefore `!(v1 && v2) = !v1 || !v2`

Comment: I believe  in given use case that's valid.  `v1 && v2` represents when both values are not `null` or `undefined`. And `!v1 && !v2` represents when both values are `null` or `undefined`. Am I missing something in this context?

Comment: There is no "type dependency" that TS can evaluate. You expect it to be able to tell that *either* `v1` *or* `v2` is falsy but *not both*. Yet the compiler cannot deduce that, it can deduce that either is falsy, therefore, each individually is `T`. Therefore, you're doing a `T ?? T` and the latter can be `null` for example. There isn't a `T but only when v2 is T2` type.

Comment: I still don't get it. If TS can evaluate `v1 && v2` and knows that any code inside that condition will narrow type for both `v1` and `v2` to `string`. Then why not `!v1 && !v2` works the same way?

Comment: Now we're back to boolean algebra. Because `!v1 && !v2` is ***not*** equivalent to `!(v1 && v2)`. It's equivalent to `!(v1 || v2)`. For example for `v1 = null` and `v2 = "foo"` that means that the `if` will not trigger. After the `if` the compiler determines that they are `T` because, as I said, the type `T but only when the other value is T2` doesn't exist. There are no dependent types. The two variables are *individually* either a `T` or a `T2` and since neither can *individually* be determined to be `T2`, they are both *individually* a `T`.

Comment: @VLAZ - I think all of that could be combined into a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of the boolean expression `v1 && v2` is not `!v1 && !v2`.

According to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B)
```

Thus the opposite would be

```
!(v1 && v2) = !v1 || !v2
```

Conversely

```
not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B)
```

Thus the first boolean expression is actually the same as a negated OR

```
!(v1 || v2) = !v1 && !v2
```

That means that the opposite (when no error would be thrown) would be a normal OR.

This is easy to prove with a boolean table:

| v1 | v2 | v1 && v2 | !v1 && !v2 | !(v1 || v2) | v1 || v2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |

---

Therefore there is no bug in TypeScript. It works respecting logic.

What is missing is that the compiler *cannot* represent the middle two rows of cases - when the values are mixed. That requires the compiler to know that the only possible pairings of types are `v1: T; v2: T2` and `v1: T2; v2: T` - yet such "dependent types" do not exist in TypeScript.

---

For example `v1 = null` and `v2 = "foo"` the `if` statement will not trigger. That means that the compiler knows that both are not `T2` at the same time. Since it cannot express "one is `T` other is `T2`". It considers each variable individually - since it cannot guarantee that `v1` is `T2`, nor can it guarantee that `v2` is `T2` (remember - no dependencies) it can only represent each variable as `T`.

This accounts for the failure to narrow after the `if`.

---

One option to make the compiler understand what you mean is

```typescript
if(!v1) {
    throw new Error('Value Error');
}

if(!v2) {
    throw new Error('Value Error');
}

const r: T2 = v1 ?? v2;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=24#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHykwFcAbE-KIzAEwgDMsJqBuKAKFElgCYFk0s2ZmzYBjAPaYUUbBGAAlCElLA+ACgCUALlgIAfFADkhqAEMksYWMnSAbgEYtcRLIVKVm4RKmrb3J3yuisokwJ4i6HRqAIQOGlAA3mxQKVDAABao4gDuhBC5AKKoWahqhgBqpiRE0EUlhhrCAL4RUbHc8UmpaZk5eYXF4qUVVTVQdUMNzSLe0qg6MLyIDlAA-KtQfsxAA)

This is logically equivalent to `!v1 && !v2` but works with the narrowing, since each variable is examined separately, thus no need for dependency between them at compiler level. After the first `if` passes, then `v1` is `T2` and nothing else. After the second `if` passes, then `v2` is `T2` and nothing else. The only way to get to `const r: T2 = v1 ?? v2` is if neither is falsy. Although, this introduces an oddity where `r` is guaranteed to only ever be `v1`.

Another option might be even simpler:

```typescript
const r: T = v1 ?? v2;

if(!r) {
    throw new Error('Value Error');
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHykwFcAbE-KIzAEwgDMsJqBuKAKFElgCYFk0s2ZmzYBjAPaYUUbBGAAlCElLA+ACgCUALlgIAfFADkhqAEMksYWMnSAbgEYtcRLIVKVm4RKmrb3J3yuisokwJ4i3tKoOs5QDlAA-Alx3FbodGoAhKgaUADebFBFUMAAFqjiAO6EENUAoqgVqGqGAGqmJETQDU2GGsIAvmxAA)

This is again logically equivalent, since the *result* of the logical operation is used. After the `if` the variable `r` is guaranteed to be `T2` because it is not falsy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detail explanations.